# Add image on top of UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I am trying to add a image banner on top of a `UIImage` before saving it. I have created this category method to do so. I have checked and rechecked that `banner.png` exists and the `gradient` shows up fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
- (UIImage *)addBanner {
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height+50));
     [self drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 50)];
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGRect bannerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, 50);
     CGColorRef start = RGB(71, 174, 255).CGColor;
     CGColorRef end = RGB(0, 80, 255).CGColor;
     drawLinearGradient(context, bannerRect, start, end);
     UIImage *bannerImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"banner.png"];
     [bannerImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
     UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     return newImage;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: I get my image with the banner gradient on top but my bannerImage isn't showing.

Comment: It turns out that bannerImage is nil so that is causing my problem. I am absolutely positive that it is in the app bundle though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add Uiimage on top of another Uiimage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523122/add-uiimage-on-top-of-another-uiimage)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` requires a full path. Changing it to `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"banner.png"]]` worked.

Comment: Or, depending on how you'll use the image, `[UIImage imageNamed:@"banner"]`. See [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [Combining Images with UIImage & CGContext – (Offscreen drawing)](http://www.trembl.org/codec/334/)

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, I tried to run this outside of my category and got the same results. Please read the issue description before providing cookie cutter responses.