# Resize UIImage for Instagram size [iOS]

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

When I captured the screen and save it as UIImage, the size will be (640x1136) , What I need exactly to set that UIImage center of plain white UIImage to post it into instagram with no crop!

I used this code for resize the UIImage but it doesn't make what I need

[UIImage+Resize](https://github.com/AliSoftware/UIImage-Resize)

from that I used this code:

```
UIImage *thenew = [NewImg resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:CGsizeMake(612,612) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
```

Hope you help me with this one

**SOLUTION By Logan**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523275/2611971

Comment: I'm not seeing 'resizedImageWithContent: bounds: interpolationQuality:' declared in UIImage+Resize? Can you show your resize method?

Comment: Logan check here http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.m

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  The method you're using should be cropping the image fine.  I don't know what "set that UIImage center of plain white uiimage" means.  Do you want a white border? If so, just look into how to add a border to a UIImage - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1358967/2611971

Comment: Logan not white border you know whitagram / nocrop applications ? you can choose the photo whatever its size you can post it to instagram

Comment: You need to have a square white image, then after you've resized the image you want to put on top of it, combine them using something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10523275/2611971

Comment: Great @haz, I added it as an answer if you'd like to accept it!

Comment: Thanks @haz, good luck with the rest of your app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image resizing is fine, you just need to combine it with a square white background image.  Use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1358967/2611971